# How to align UI popup panel to Button's edge?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a "Screen Space - Camera" Canvas in Unity with several buttons inside. When I click a button, it opens a popup (UI Panel), outside of the button's parent, which I want to align to the specific button I pressed. I can position it over the button by simply matching its "rectTransform.position" to the button's rectTransform.position, but that just centers it over the button. I want its edge to line up with the edge of the button's edge.

I tried to get the width of the button and the width of the popup and then just shift it over by the width / 2, but the problem is the values are way off because of the type of canvas I'm using (I'm assuming that's issue). I can't change the canvas type for my game.  I tried using Canvas.scaleFactor too, but it doesn't seem to work or I don't know how to use it.

The other big issue is that the button is deep down in the Canvas's hierarchy, but the popup is a direct child of the Canvas.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
// Popup position & size
RectTransform popupPOS = popupCanvas.transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>(); 
float popupRealWidth = popupPOS.rect.width * mainCanvas.scaleFactor;

// Button position & size
RectTransform btnPOS = gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
float btnRealWidth = btnPOS.rect.width * mainCanvas.scaleFactor;

// Position popup to position of button
popupCanvas.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = new Vector3(btnPOS.position.x, btnPOS.position.y, btnPOS.position.z);

// Move Rect.x by "RealWidth"
popupPOS.localPosition = new Vector3(popupPOS.localPosition.x + popupRealWidth / 2, popupPOS.localPosition.y, popupPOS.localPosition.z);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Here it is in case anyone is trying to figure this out in the future.

There was no need to use "scaleFactor". I feel like I tried this before and it didn't work. Maybe it's because I didn't follow the "PEMDAS" rule...sigh. My high school math teacher would be shaking her head.

```
popupPos.localPosition = new Vector3(popupPos.localPosition.x + (popupPos.rect.width / 2) + (btnPos.rect.width / 2), popupPos.localPosition.y - (popupPos.rect.height / 2) + (btnPos.rect.height / 2), popupPos.localPosition.z);
```

This aligns the popup (ui panel) to the top right of the button.

Answer (score -1):

```
this.Parent = gameObject; //Or whatever your button is named

this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
```

I believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't think this would work, since the popup can't be a children of the button. The way Unity hierarchy works, it hides the popup behind all the other canvas elements. The popup needs to remain as a direct child of the canvas and at the bottom of the hierarchy, unfortunately.